# Implementing a refactoring system for my autogenerated code

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have a little visual system for generation FSM's where the user can draw a graph using boxes (states) and link them with lines (transitions). This, in the end, generates c# code when user presses the "Generate code" button that defines the FSM in runtime.

I want my users to be able to change things like graph name, transitions names, states names, delete nodes, delete transitions and a bit more after the first save, so, I need a way to handle refactoring.

I'm struggling trying to find a non intrusive way to accomplish this. Have tried to apply a modification of a do/redo algorithm I made some time ago but couldn't be able to get something nice.

Could anyone explain how to create such a system, making it as less intrussive with existent code as possible?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest keeping the state in your graph datastructure, and generating the C# code anew on changes to the FSM, this is a simple solution that will allow arbitrary modification of the FSM-datastructure without having to worry about applying said modifications to the generated code.

For implementing 'refactorings' of the base FSM-data structure, you could use something like a [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) to encapsulate the refactorings and undo/redo operations.

Comment: I understand what you mean but one requirement is to "buffer" the changes and apply them in the end after the user wants to generate all the files for his new modified FSM.

Comment: That would be possible using a command pattern too -- you could store a sequence of commands and apply them at once.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was trying to apply using my previous undo/redo system. One key point here is to generate uniques ids for each object that want any of its properties to be tracked for changes. For example, if user changes a State name, I should be able to identify the change independenly of the name of the node. Perhaps I could use just the node refernce as the PK.  Well it seems, I wasn't to far from the solution. Will try to rething my initial design that was based on commands too. Just did not like it to couple the refactor sytem with each class that wants to use the refactoring system.

Comment: It would be fine to change the identity of state objects during a command, so long as the command object holds both the new and the previous identity, so the operation can be both applied and undone. I would suggest making your command objects work against an FSM interface, so you don't couple the refactor system with the implementation of the FSM.

Comment: what do you mean by identity?

Comment: Anything you would use to uniquely identify a state node, given an FSM. For C# you should override the equality operator to implement it.